# How can I increment a number in a file by an amount?

Tags: java, io

I have got a .txt file which stores a players' money. I need this file to increment or detriment a certain amount depending on if the player kills something or if they buy something from the shop.

The issue is that I do not know how to actually increment or detriment the contents. I can delete/recreate the .txt file with the new money, however because multiple threads will be accessing the file, then there is the risk that the file may not exist due to it being deleted and not regenerated yet.

Just to clarify, there will only be one thread at a time modifying the file. Other threads will only be reading the file.

So how would I do this without deleting the data/file first?

Comment: Can you not keep the contents of the file in memory while the program is running and only write/read from the file at program startup/shutdown?

Comment: @user3580294 Because my game is in early beta, there will be a lot of exploits and bugs which will crash the server.  I did save it into memory on another game which I am working on, however even though it is incredibly rare, when the server crashes then players can lose days of work.

I would prefer to have it where it is impossible to lose, rather than having a chance to lose it.

Comment: I see... If periodically writing to disk from time to time won't work, perhaps check out [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)?

Comment: I assume, that your game is a network game. Think about using a database instead of storing statistics in files.

Comment: @ChristianSt. I will look into it. Meanwhile, I will use flatfile.

Comment: Simultaneously updating a file from multiple threads is a bad idea. I think you should use a database. If you have two few things to save in the database, at least make sure the file is open, read, written, and closed by one and only one `synchronized` function.

Comment: @Krumia Added into main post - "Just to clarify, there will only be one thread at a time modifying the file. Other threads will only be reading the file.".

I will not be modifying it from multiple threads, because the player can only be logging in (creates file if not existing), in battle (Killing people for money) and in the shop (Buying stuff) at one time. So, while multiple threads have code to modify the file, only one will actually be modifying it at any one time. The others will just be reading it.

Comment: You write, that your game is in `early beta state`. If you develop tons of lines of code, storing statistics based on plain text files and you actually know that's a bad idea (as mentioned in these comments), why don't you want to go `the right way` from beginning? That will save a lot of time on refactoring later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code ,read file first and then increment it and store again -

```
   BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {

        // Read File Contents - score
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\a.txt"));
        String storedScore="0";
        int storedScoreNumber = 0;
        while ((storedScore = br.readLine()) != null) {
            storedScoreNumber=(Integer.parseInt(storedScore==null?"0":storedScore));
        }

        // Write File Contents - incremented socre
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\a.txt", false));
        out.write(String.valueOf(storedScoreNumber+1));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Writing a single number in a file wont take that much time, so in your case I don't think there is too much risk of absence of thread synchronization..in fraction of second other user will get new value..

Comment: For some reason it is meant to give the person "50" money, but instead if gives 3950?
Now it was 3950, and then it went to 7000 or something like that? What the hell?

Answer (score 0):

Have a singleton data accessor with a queue so that it is the only one manipulating the file. If necessary acknowledge to client threads after the write.